# Generic C++14 lambdas and relationship with templates

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I did read that C++14 generic lambdas with `auto` parameters are actually templates, so the following is valid C++14

```
auto glambda = [] (auto a) { return a; };
cout << glambda(23); // Prints 23
cout << glambda('A'); // Prints A
```

This doesn't quite stack up with what I know from templates.. where's the instantiation point? What is it stored in the `glambda` variable if the first call instantiates a template with `int` and the second one with `char`?

Comment: [This talk at cppcon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXeu4fj3zOs) is very relevant (and good!). *"Lambdas from First Principles: A Whirlwind Tour of C++"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that the "lambda is a template" -- that doesn't make sense, a lambda is an expression. Rather, the *type* of the closure object that's defined by the lambda expression has an overloaded function call operator that is defined by a member function template. So the instantiation point is the first use of the respective call operator.

In other words, a lambda `[a, &b](auto x, auto y) -> R { /* ... */ }` has a type like:

```
struct __lambda
{
    __lambda(const A & __a, B & __b) : a(__a), b(__b) {}

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    R operator()(T1 x, T2 y) const { /* ... */ }

private:
    A a;
    B & b;
};
```

Comment: "All names starting with `__` are merely exposition." might be useful.  Or not; but I like making that clear.  Aside: `/* ... */` -- C++ robot is unimpressed by this code smiley.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "A& a" as a member?

Comment: @Wiertek No?  The lambda captured `a` by value, not by reference.

Comment: Although the parameter should probably be `A& __a`.

Answer (score 4):

A generic lambda is an object of a compiler generated type that has a template method called `operator()`. Your code can be rewritten with this equivalent:

```
struct MyLambda {
    template<typename T>
    T operator() (T val) {
        return val;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyLambda func;

    std::cout << func('A');
    std::cout << func(42);
}
```

The compiler will instantiate `operator()` when needed.

Hope it helped

Comment: A generic lambda is not an object with a templated method, even if there exists an equivalence.

Comment: Well... As far as I know, lambda are objects of a compiler generated class. In this case, the object has a template method called `operator()`.

Comment: @skypjack What?  A lambda has to be some sort of object with a `operator()`  The only way in the current standard to translate `[a, &b](auto x, auto y)` into a function call is to use a template and let template argument deduction take place.

Comment: @skypjack The standard says: *The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion
class type*.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot A better version (from the standard) would be an unamed class declared inside the main function with only one instance (func).

Comment: @NathanOliver It does have some weirdness compared to "plain" objects, but I have no idea what @ skypjack is talking about.

Comment: @T.C. Agree.  They may not be exactly the same but is is a class type with a template `operator ()`.

Comment: Well, a generic lambda is a bit more than *an object with a templated method*. As an example, a non capturing one has the operator `operator ret(*)(params)()`, and so on. Trying to enrich an answer is not a crime yet, right? I wish generic lambdas had been designed as *an object with a templated method*, so simpler to understand!! Anyway, if it's good for the OP (who doesn't know what's a lambda and won't know it with such an answer), it's good for me.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, *it is as a*, not only *it is a*. This would be *correct* (at least, not so *wrong*). My two cents.

Comment: @skypjack An answer is not enriched by adding details that are not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Oktalist You are right, I didn't want to add useless details (the operator was an example to explain why it is not only *an object with a templated method*, no need to add it).